# Cannot get Jupyter Notebook To Run - "Cannot Import Name AsyncGenerator"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this problem?  I am NOT using Anaconda.  The version of Jupyter I have is 1.0.0.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 13, in <module>
    from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\embed.py", line 16, in <module>
    from IPython.terminal.interactiveshell import TerminalInteractiveShell
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\interactiveshell.py", line 19, in <module>
    from prompt_toolkit.enums import DEFAULT_BUFFER, EditingMode
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .application import Application
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\application\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .application import Application
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\application\application.py", line 38, in <module>
    from prompt_toolkit.buffer import Buffer
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\buffer.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .application.current import get_app
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\application\current.py", line 8, in <module>
    from prompt_toolkit.eventloop.dummy_contextvars import ContextVar  # type: ignore
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\eventloop\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .async_generator import generator_to_async_generator
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\eventloop\async_generator.py", line 5, in <module>
    from typing import AsyncGenerator, Callable, Iterable, TypeVar, Union
ImportError: cannot import name 'AsyncGenerator'
```

Much thanks.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I am using version 3.6.0

Answer (score 16):

The reason is that the version of prompt_toolkit does not match  Python 3.6

The solution is to reduce the version

```
pip install --upgrade prompt-toolkit==2.0.1
```

Answer (score 5):

According to a Github issue related to the same error text: https://github.com/python/typing/issues/530, this is a bug that is fixed in Python 3.6.1.

Since you are using Python 3.6.0, you should upgrade your version to 3.6.1 or higher to fix the issue.

Alternatively, a workaraound is to set

```
if TYPE_CHECKING: from typing import AsyncGenerator
```

Comment: sorry to revive it, but where exactly should I set it?
i'm having same issue but i can't upgrade to 3.6.1 due to my project limitations, so i need to stick with this workaround

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in CONDA environment:

1. Had to uninstall the package like this:

`conda remove -n pyspark_env prompt_toolkit`

2. Installed again as mentioned [here](https://pypi.org/project/prompt-toolkit/):

`conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge prompt_toolkit`

**Python 3.7, prompt_toolkit - 3.0.2, November 2021**

Answer (score -1):

I got this error on py3.9 and to resolve it I had to change the resolver to be compatible.

Try running:

```bash
pip3 install jupyter --use-feature=2020-resolver
```