# Jupyter notebook not working in VScode because of ipykernel

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently attempting to use jupyter notebook in VScode. I've downloaded the Python and Juypter notebook extensions. Whenever I try to run the code a prompt appears: [image]

click Install and I get this error message:  Installing ipykernel: WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None,
re... module is not available.")': /simple/ipykernel/

It also shows this message: Running cells with 'Python 3.9.12 ('work_env': venv)' requires ipykernel package.
Run the following command to install 'ipykernel' into the Python environment.
Command: 'c:/EmgProj/work_env/Scripts/python.exe -m pip install ipykernel -U --force-reinstall'

If I use the code suggested above in the terminal, it successfully installs the extension but it still says I don't ipykernel when I try to run it. Can someone help please?

Comment: Are you installing in the correct environment? You can refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64997553/python-requires-ipykernel-to-be-installed).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you, reinstalling ipykernel still didn't work, finally I found

pip uninstall pyzmq

pip install pyzmq

works.
The links below may be helpful:

[Failed to change the Jupyter Kernel in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67818911/failed-to-change-the-jupyter-kernel-in-vs-code/67833255#67833255)

[I get an error while installing ipykernel on vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74231947/i-get-an-error-while-installing-ipykernel-on-vscode)