# I get an error while installing ipykernel on vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, jupyter-notebook

When I was running a jupyter note on vscode

`

```
# Load the libraries to be used in the Analysis

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
impor wat warnings

# Setup libraries settings and options
## Pandas setup
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

## matplotlib setup
%matplotlib inline

## Seaborn setup
sns.set_context('notebook')
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
sns.set_palette('Blues_r')

# turn off warning for final notebook
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

`

I then got asked to install ipykernel, when i choose install from vscode the process starts then i get this error message:
Running cells with 'Python 3.11.0 64-bit' requires ipykernel package.
Run the following command to install 'ipykernel' into the Python environment.
Command: 'c:/Users/Samir/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe -m pip install ipykernel -U --user --force-reinstall'

I go to Git Bash and run

```
python -m pip install ipykernel
```

I get this Error

```
\tests
      running build_ext
      building 'psutil._psutil_windows' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Micr
osoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tool
s/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem wit
h pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psutil
Failed to build psutil
ERROR: Could not build wheels for psutil, which is required to install pyproject
.toml-based projects
```

I tried to install the ipykernel from vscode then from Git bash but i get an Error

Comment: Have you tried what the message suggests? `c:/Users/Samir/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe -m pip install ipykernel -U --user --force-reinstall`. And in fact it also suggests getting a compiler from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Comment: i use `vs code` in `windows` and it works from the prompt inside `vs code`. I believe it installs the `jupyter` extension...

Answer (score 2):

> 'c:/Users/Samir/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe -m
> pip install ipykernel -U --user --force-reinstall'

Obviously, it has told you how to install.

But please note that this is an environmental issue, so make sure you choose the correct interpreter.

You can use the shortcut key `Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new VScode terminal, it will automatically enter the currently selected VSCode environment.

And use command `pip install ipykernel` to install ipykernel.

**Alternative method:**

Use following command in the terminal to reinstall pyzmq package.

```
pip uninstall pyzmq
pip install pyzmq
```