# Why does this keep happening?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter, python-3.8

I have installed opencv in python 3.8.8 version and my vscode works fine only in 3.8.3 version and whenever I try to change the version to 3.8.8 version it keeps asking me to re-install the path. Can any of you'll help?

[image]

Comment: Can you please give us more information on what you are trying to do? Did you activate conda enviroment when you try to run the script (conda enviroment do not use system python interpreter and that is the reason why everyone use it! Thats the point behind virtual enviroments)

Comment: This question is possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64997553/python-requires-ipykernel-to-be-installed

Comment: @Pr0ph3t_sec Yes, I have activated conda base before running the code. I am trying to use opencv but everytime I run the program using this version, the popup is seen and when I click re-install, it installs and when I run, same thing happens again

Comment: Please write python3 -c 'import cv2;print(cv2.__version__)' in the activated conda enviroment terminal/cmd. Do you have any tracebacks? Please post the output of command 'where python3' in cmd and 'which python3' in terminal with activated conda enviroment (terminal/cmd should be with prefix which will be name of the enviroment)

Answer (score 0):

[The error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxqUH.png)

I think the error is explicit, it says you need to install the package `ipykernel` which is not actualy present or have to be updated in order to be used with the python 3.8.8.